# What version of Bloodlines & Black Magic has a "LCK" attribute on its character sheet?

Tags: product-identification, character-sheets

What version of Bloodlines & Black Magic is [this character sheet](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/264821/Bloodlines--Black-Magic-Character-Sheet) for?  It has a "LCK" attribute in addition to the usual d20 STR, CON, DEX etc. Contrariwise, the version of Bloodlines and Black Magic I purchased has a "THreshhold" attribute on the character sheet but no "LCK".  I conclude, then, that the 2 sheets are for different editions.

***Is*** the game with the "LCK" attribute a newer edition?  What does "LCK" abbreviate?

Answer (score 3):

### LCK is Luck based on the [Quick-Start Rules](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/401194/The-Bloodlines--Black-Magic-Roleplaying-Game-Quick-Start-Guide?manufacturers_id=4518)

I grabbed a copy of the [Quick-Start-Guide, June 2022](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/401194/The-Bloodlines--Black-Magic-Roleplaying-Game-Quick-Start-Guide?manufacturers_id=4518) of the game, and its Charsheet features "LCK" in the middle between the standard d20 attributes:

[image: Snippet from the Quickstart-guide's char sheet, top left corner]

This shorthand is not referenced anywhere else, but it **is** talked about on page 1 of the Quick-Start Rules, which implies that the Abbreviation LCK stands for Luck:

> - The Bloodlines & Black Magic Roleplaying Game uses
>   seven ability scores (instead of six), **adding Luck** as an
>   ability score to the traditional six: Strength, Dexterity,
>   Constitution, Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma.

The page also says something about compatibility (emphasis mine):

> **The original edition** of the Bloodlines & Black Magic Roleplaying Game was designed to be compatible with the **first edition of
> the Pathfinder Roleplaying Game**.
>
> **This edition** of the game has instead been designed to showcase its compatibility with the **5e-version of the d20 system**. We hope
> that, with this PDF, players familiar with other 5e or d20-based games will find learning to play the Bloodlines & Black Magic
> Roleplaying Game more enjoyable. Players familiar with 5e-based games should note the following: [...]

So, the QSG is for [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e).

### LCK is retained on the official char sheet

The [official character sheet](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/264821/Bloodlines--Black-Magic-Character-Sheet?manufacturers_id=4518) is the same as in the quickstart rules, so again, it would mean Luck. It is thus also for [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e).

### Is it an Edition conflict?

There are currently two different Editions in existence, as far as I could find out:

- The 2018(?) [Pathfinder 1e version](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/240250/Bloodlines--Black-Magic?manufacturers_id=4518),
- The 2019/20 [Dungeons and Dragons 5e version](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/335318/The-Bloodlines--Black-Magic-Core-Rulebook-BW?manufacturers_id=4518) (which has a colored and B&W  version) and for which the Quick-Start guide was written.

**The two games are totally separate**. The whole game was rewritten from Pathfinder 1e to D&D 5e, as page 2 of the edition for D&D 5e tells (visible in the sample file) with emphasis added. In fact, that part even implies the two are not fully compatible:

> Within weeks of releasing the original version of Bloodlines & Black Magic, individuals immediately began to ask — can we get this in 5e?
>
> For well over a year we spent days and nights working on conversions, all while trying to ensure that we didn't lose any of the elements that make *Bloodlines & Black Magic* what it is; at the end of 2019 **we decided to write this as its own game.**
>
> *Bloodlines & Black Magic* uses the OGL but has otherwise been redesigned to accommodate the setting in which we want to play.

### Conclusion

Whatever version **you** own, the character sheet belongs to the exact *other* version, as do the Quick-Start rules. And since the Quick-Start belongs to the [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) edition, **you own the [pathfinder-1e](/questions/tagged/pathfinder-1e) edition.**